# PHP not processing in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have created a try_files directive that tries files in a different directory than the files are put in. I.e., if I visit `www.example.com/home/main` it will try the file `/var/www/main/home/main.php`. It works, but when I visit a page, it only shows the PHP source code and not the processed page. Here is my directive:

```
location ~ /home/ {
   index main.php
   try_files /main$uri.php @404;
   location \.php {
       fastcgi_pass php_server;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the page to process instead of just showing the PHP source?

Edit for additional information: I have tried making a location directive that looks like

```
location ~ /main/(.*)\.php {
       fastcgi_pass php_server;
       include fastcgi_params;
}
```

but this doesn't work either and the pages still show just the source code.

Comment: Yes, I made a `location ~ \.php` to process PHP files in the root directory, and those work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will show you source, since you don't have `fastcgi_pass` in your `/home/` location.

Try this one:

```
location /home/ {
   try_files /main$uri.php @static;
   fastcgi_pass php_server;
   include fastcgi_params;
}

location @static { }
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I guess it's because I'm not serving PHP files directly with an extension `.php`?

Comment: From [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) documentation: _the processing is performed in the current context._ And note, that every request is processed only in one location context. In your configuration it was either `location \.php` or `location ~ /home/`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I had everything right but the php code was using php short tags so I had to `set short_open_tag=On` in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini then restart `service php5-fpm restart`

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Actually the below is wrong - the last parameter is always used as a redirect if the file can't be found anywhere else in the `try_files` directive. In this example, it is hitting the .php file, but not be processed, so the `@404` wasn't being hit. However, if no `@404` example exists, then a failure to find the file would blow up anyways.

> In the event that no file is found, an internal redirect to the last parameter is invoked [...]The last parameter is the fallback URI and *must* exist, or else an internal error will be raised.

source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

<strike>The `@404` at the end of your `try_files` directive will send the php file to be parsed by a `location @404` directive, not your php directive that uses fastcgi.</strike>

Try dropping the `@404` or simple doing: `try_files $uri /main$uri.php;`

Comment: When I removed the `@404` from the `try_files` it still brought up the page with the PHP source code.

Comment: So when you visit something at `/home/page.php` it works fine?

Comment: When I visit something at `/home.php` it works fine, but that is because I have a location directive specifically for the `/` directory, but not other ones. I tried to change the location directive to reflect `/home/` or `/main/home/` but neither work.

Comment: Please write your answer such that it makes sense for the first time reader; the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15005756/revisions) lets anyone see what changed.